# Whatsapp message to a number programatically is not working in release version of android apk

Tags: android, android-studio, whatsapp

Below is the code I used for sending messages to WhatsApp number through the android app

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

try {
    String phone="+919999999999";
    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+ phone +"&text=" + URLEncoder.encode("hello", "UTF-8");
    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
        this.startActivity(i);
    }
}
catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

it is working fine in debug version of the app, but not working in the release version. nothing happens after pressing send button, neither it shows an exception.

Comment: what does the logs say?

Comment: All of a sudden it started working, much sorry for a late reply.. thanks too for taking ur taking :)